# ListView only one list entry play button works

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview

I'm trying to make a ListView activity following the example from this website

http://cyrilmottier.com/2011/11/23/listview-tips-tricks-4-add-several-clickable-areas/

in which I'm using data from my database and using a BaseAdapter everything seems to work fine (the onListItemClick,the textview loading my data) but my "play" button on the right of the list items will not work.I am using a framelayout in my list-items xml if that helps.

---UPDATE---

None of those answers solved my question but after fiddling around I got the first entry play button working but the other entry play buttons do not work only the first one works.
Here is the new codes for my list activity and xml.

PlayAFriend Activity

```
    package com.fullfrontalgames.numberfighter;
import com.fullfrontalgames.numberfighter.DBAdapter;
import com.fullfrontalgames.numberfighter.R;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;



import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;


import android.view.View;


import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import android.widget.Toast;





public class PlayAFriend extends ListActivity{
    DBAdapter DBAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_items);

        final DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
        DBAdapter = db.open();




        ListView FriendLV = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        Button playbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playbutton);



        FriendLV.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });
        playbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent("com.fullfrontalgames.numberfighter.Fightattacker"));
            }
        });


Cursor friendslist = db.GetAllFriends();

        String[] from = new String[] {"FRIENDS"};   // your column/columns here
        int[] to = new int[] {R.id.textview_friends};

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        ListAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_items, friendslist, from, to,0);
          FriendLV.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);








    }


}
```

list_items xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView 
            android:id="@android:id/list"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="vertical" >

        </ListView>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/searchimageview"
        android:orientation="vertical" >



<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/textview_friends"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="40dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

<Button
        android:id="@+id/playbutton"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="@drawable/playbutton" />


    </FrameLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: your play button is outside the listview. Do you have play button for each row in the list

Comment: @Raghunandan my play button is outside the listview because I can't use a Button widget in a ListView,would I have to make a playbutton for every entry in the listview?Keep in mind my list is from a SQLitedatabase from when a player adds someone to their friendslist so that could be from 5 friends to 100 friends depending on the person.

Comment: you gave a link that link has a button in each listview row. So if the button is outside. Then on click listener will work for that button not for each item in the row.

Comment: @Raghunandan Is there a way I could accomplish this with the code I have?I know in the link I gave it refers to how to accomplish this when you add your entries in a String Array but how would I accomplish the same effect from user inputted entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update

Sorry for the late update but I sovled this issue on my own by adding a android:onClick attribute to my play button and then defining the public onButtonClick method in my class.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/playbutton"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:onClick="OnButtonClick"
    android:background="@drawable/playbutton" />
```

Class

```
public void OnButtonClick(View view) {
    startActivity(new Intent(
            "com.fullfrontalgames.numberfighter.Fightattacker"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you are in wrong way.You have to try this link insted of `textView` you have to used `button`.
http://wowjava.wordpress.com/2011/03/26/dynamic-listview-in-android/

If you have any problem then let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below

In getView()

```
 Button b=(Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.playbutton);
 b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
 {
       if (position != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
                        startActivity(newIntent("com.fullfrontalgames.numberfighter.Fightattacker"));
                }
 });
```

Also you should be using a ViewHolder for smooth scrolling and performance. Details of which are available in the link below.

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html