# Dialog only first option works

Tags: java, android, dialog

I'm trying to make a SingleChoiceItems dialog activated from a listview onItemLongCLick which has 3 options via radiobuttons 1.View Profile 2.Send Message 3.Delete Friends and from the way I have it set up,only the first option toast works on all 3 options.
How would I make it that options 2 and 3 does their actions instead of doing option 1's actions?

Here is the code to my dialog,

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    String[] items = { "View Profile", "Send Message", "Remove Friend" };
    final DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
    db.open();

    switch (id) {
    case 0:
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                .setTitle("Select a option")
                .setSingleChoiceItems(items, id,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                int choice = 0;
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                mChoice = choice;
                            }
                        })

                .setPositiveButton("OK", new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int choice) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if (mChoice == 0) {
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Test 1",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else if (mChoice == 1) {
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Test2",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else if (mChoice == 2) {
                            TextView friends = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_friends);
                            String deletedfriend = friends.getText()
                                    .toString();
                            db.DeleteFriends(deletedfriend);
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                                    "Friend Removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    }
                }

                )

                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int choice) {

                    }
                })

                .create();

    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: why do you take out the listener for SingleChoiceItems? put it back and It will be OK.

Comment: @HoanNguyen I didn't this it was necessary I putted it back on but it's still the same.

Comment: @HoanNguyen Thank you very much for telling me to include "which" now I can select all options!

Comment: Do you still need help on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15870742/listview-only-one-list-entry-play-button-works

Comment: @HoanNguyen thanks for the offer but I solved this one a few days ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove choice = 0;

```
.setSingleChoiceItems(items, id,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {

                            mChoice = which;
                        }
                    })
```